# Moving Spring/Hibernate XML reference in web.xml breaks it -- why?

Tags: spring, hibernate, web.xml

I'm coding a Spring/Hibernate program and starting with a internet example.  I copied the example, fussed with a lot of configuration issues and got the front page working.

I don't like the way I set up the web.xml page.  I want to move the hibernate-context.xml from the servlet section to the earlier context-param section.  Gathering XML references is a pattern that I've seen on other sites.

This change isn't working for me.  Can someone tell me why?  I've included my XML setup below.

For setup "B", here is the startup log:

```
[snip]
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jan 03 20:10:41 CST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/hibernate-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring.properties]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1b071c0: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,sessionFactory,dataSource,transactionManager]; root of factory hierarchy
[snip]

INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Thu Jan 03 20:10:44 CST 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
[snip]
```

In both the "good" and "bad" setups the Hibernate XML is loaded.  The "good" setup does it sooner, of course.

```
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/hibernate-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring.properties]
```

When I try the web page with the "bad" setup I get this exception:

```
Jan 3, 2013 8:12:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/ticketexchange] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread] with root cause
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:941)
    at org.krams.tutorial.service.PersonService.getAll(PersonService.java:40)
    at org.krams.tutorial.controller.MainController.getRecords(MainController.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[snip]
```

Can someone explain this?

Here are my configuration files:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>    <!-- This setup "A" works -->
        <!-- <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/hibernate-context.xml</param-value> -->       <!-- Once the commented sections are shifted, this setup "B" fails -->
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml  /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/hibernate-context.xml</param-value>    <!-- This setup "A" works -->
            <!-- <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value> -->        <!-- Once the commented sections are shifted, this setup "B" fails -->
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

hibernate-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      ">

 <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring.properties" />

    <!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Declare the Hibernate SessionFactory for retrieving Hibernate sessions -->
    <!-- See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html -->       
 <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html -->
 <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/Session.html -->
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
     p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
     p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
     p:packagesToScan="org.krams.tutorial"/>

 <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities--> 
 <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
    p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
    p:acquireIncrement="5"
    p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
    p:maxPoolSize="100"
    p:maxStatements="50"
    p:minPoolSize="10" />

 <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

</beans>
```

spring.properties:

```
# database properties
app.jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
app.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_database
app.jdbc.username=my_username
app.jdbc.password=my_password

#hibernate properties
hibernate.config=/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/hibernate.cfg.xml
```

hibernate.cfg.xml, declared within spring.properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
   <!-- We're using MySQL database so the dialect needs to MySQL as well-->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
    <!-- Enable this to see the SQL statements in the logs-->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <!-- This will drop our existing database and re-create a new one.
      Existing data will be deleted! -->
    <!--<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>-->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

     <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.krams.tutorial" />



</beans:beans>
```

root-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the answer to your question, but the right way to move it to the 'context-param' section is to load your hibernate-context.xml in the root-context.xml file. Just add this line

```
<import resource="hibernate-context.xml" /> //Assuming both are in the same folder
```

The servlet part of your new web.xml will look like this

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml <param-value>    
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

And your root-context.xml will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
<import resource="hibernate-context.xml" /> //Assuming both are in the same folder

</beans>
```

**Solution for your problem**

Seperate your component scan for transactional classess and controllers.
ie in your servlet-context.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.krams.tutorial.yourControllerpackage" />
```

And in your hibernate-context.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.krams.tutorial.yourDaoServicePackage" />
```

The reason is explained [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-i-resolved)

Comment: After applying your solution I *do* get the promised good results. I thank you for bringing it to my attention.  I'll have to study the pages, and more Spring, though because the *why* doesn't really make sense yet.  Apparently the "annotation-driven" tag does quite a bit of magic!